# How do I map from a source property to the destination?

Tags: automapper-2

I swear I've done it before, but I can't seem to get it to work now.  Basically I'm getting an `EndUser` containing a `Site`, and I want to map that `Site` to a `SiteInfo` object.

Here's my map configuration:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Site, SiteInfo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SiteID, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.ID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Company.ID));

Mapper.CreateMap<EndUser, SiteInfo>()                
    .ForMember( dest => dest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Site ));
```

So `EndUser.Site` should be able to map to `SiteInfo`. I can do this on the outside by just calling `Mapper.Map<SiteInfo>(EndUser.Site)`. I think it's just cleaner syntax to map from the end user to the location info directly.

So how can I map directly from `EndUser` to `SiteInfo`?  Basically this is the code I'd LIKE to write:

```
var user = mcp.Users.GetEndUser(userAddress.Address);
var siteInfo = Mapper.Map<SiteInfo>(user);
```

Currently I'm working around the issue by just mapping from `EndUser.Site` like this:

```
var user = GetEndUser(emailAddress);
            var siteInfo = user == null 
                            ? null as SiteInfo 
                            : Mapper.Map<SiteInfo>(user.Site);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to map `Location` to `SiteInfo` or `LocationInfo`? What is the `dest` property you're mapping to in your `EndUser` -> `SiteInfo` mapping? Does `SiteInfo` contain a combination of both `Location` and `EndUser` properties?

Without that info I'm only guessing, but are you trying to do something like this?

```cs
var rc = Mapper.Map<SiteInfo>(endUser);
rc = Mapper.Map(endUser.Location, rc);
```

**UPDATE**

So if I understand correctly, you're after a mapping like this?

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<EndUser, SiteInfo>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SiteID, opt => opt.MapFrom( src => src.Site.ID))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.CompanyID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Site.Company.ID));
```

Comment: Edited to answer some of your questions and make things more clear (Location should really be Site throughout the example, but I switched names midway through the project. )